# using struts2 alongwith jsp servlet module

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, struts2

I want to develop a module using Struts 2 framework as instructed by my PM.

We have already developed 2 modules in the same application (in a single WAR file) using plain JSP, Servlets, and jQuery.

Can I develop the remaining 4 modules using Struts2 and keep the existing servlet-baed modules running without any problem in same WAR file?

Please advise what course of action I should follow?

Comment: Why do you want to develop modules?

Comment: Just try it and IF you have some problems come back and ask question about specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You just need to include struts dispatcher in web.xml file and also write all your action class mapping in struts.xml

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy to do like that. And it is good is you use core Servlet with Sturts2. For that you have to just configure web.xml.

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
 <display-name>Struts2 + Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/helloWorld</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
                org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```